# Problems with BlendOp Max

Tags: unity, fragment-shader, shaderlab

I'm trying to write a shader that doesn't blend additively etc etc. I'd like to take whichever of the source or destination colours is brighter and use that and `BlendOp Max` seemed like the tool for the job.

However, as you can see below, the shadow of one light seems to be occluding the other, which doesn't match up with how I understand `BlendOp Max` is supposed to work:

- [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.BlendOp.Max.html)
- [NVidia](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/Cg/BlendOp.html)
- [OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Blending#Blend_Equations)

Could anyone clarify where I'm going wrong or provide an alternative?

Interestingly, `Blend One One` is working fine, however, `BlendOp Add` (along with all the other `BlendOp`s apart from the 'logical' ones) are creating the same issue.

[image: Two point lights on the plane, the shadow of one occludes the illumination of the other]

**Update**

Shader Code:

```
Shader "Lantern/Flat Pullup" {
Properties {
    _LitTex ("Lit (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _UnlitTex ("Unlit (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Pullup ("Pull up Point", Range(0,1)) = 0.7
    _BlendSize ("Blend Size", Float) = 0.3
}
SubShader {
    Pass{
        Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
        LOD 200

        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        uniform sampler2D _UnlitTex;
        uniform float4 _UnlitTex_ST;
        uniform sampler2D _LitTex;
        uniform float4 _LitTex_ST;
        uniform float _Pullup;
        uniform float _BlendSize;

        uniform float4 _LightColor0;

        struct VI {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct V2F {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        V2F vert(VI v){
            V2F o;
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.tex = v.tex;
            o.posWorld = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(V2F i) : COLOR {
            float3 flatReflection = _LightColor0.xyz * 
                (1 / length(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - i.posWorld.xyz));

            return lerp(
                tex2D(_UnlitTex, i.tex.xy * _UnlitTex_ST.xy + _UnlitTex_ST.zw),
                tex2D(_LitTex, i.tex.xy * _LitTex_ST.xy + _LitTex_ST.zw),
                clamp((length(flatReflection) - _Pullup + _BlendSize) / (2 * _BlendSize), 0, 1)
            );

        }

        ENDCG
    }

    Pass{
        Tags{"LightMode" = "ForwardAdd"}
        //Blend One One
        BlendOp Max
        LOD 200
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        uniform sampler2D _UnlitTex;
        uniform float4 _UnlitTex_ST;
        uniform sampler2D _LitTex;
        uniform float4 _LitTex_ST;
        uniform float _Pullup;
        uniform float _BlendSize;

        uniform float4 _LightColor0;

        struct VI {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct V2F {
            float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
            float4 tex : TEXCOORD0;
            float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD1;
        };

        V2F vert(VI v){
            V2F o;
            o.pos = mul(UNITY_MATRIX_MVP, v.vertex);
            o.tex = v.tex;
            o.posWorld = mul(_Object2World, v.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        float4 frag(V2F i) : COLOR {
            float3 flatReflection = _LightColor0.xyz * 
                (1 / length(_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - i.posWorld.xyz));
            return lerp(
                float4(0,0,0,1),
                tex2D(_LitTex, i.tex.xy * _LitTex_ST.xy + _LitTex_ST.zw),
                clamp((length(flatReflection) - _Pullup + _BlendSize) / (2 * _BlendSize), 0, 1)
            );
        }
        ENDCG

    }
}   
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

**Update 2**

The same plane and lights rendered using Unity's standard shader, for illustrative purposes.
[image: Two point lights on a plane, rendered using Unity's standard shader]

Comment: What geometry setup are we looking at here? Is this two overlapping quads? If so, the one behind might be getting rejected by the depth buffer. Sharing your queue and Z-Write/Z-Test settings would help diagnose the issue.

Comment: It's in unity, so the plane asset. Shader is written as a vert-frag shader in ShaderLab/CG. Note that the 'line of doom', as I've called it, moves in some way that's dependant on the camera and doesn't lie along an edge boundary or similar..

Comment: That doesn't answer the question, unfortunately. Including your shader code in the question would help. Can you also clarify where these two shapes are coming from — are these two lights or two projectors shining onto one plane, or part of the texturing effect you've applied to its surface...?

Comment: **Added shader code.** The 'shapes' is the lighting from two point lights. The colours are part of one of the textures on the object (the `_LitTex` in the shader, the `_UnlitTex` is just black)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, that even though the OpenGL documentation says the Max/Min functions don't take your blend factors into consideration, some quirk in shaderlab means you have to specify them anyway.

As such, the lonely `BlendOp Max` should be have `Blend One One` (or suitable) specified as well.